# Disappear internal purchases

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

There was such a problem. Users are upgraded to Windows Phone 8.1 and eventually they disappear internal purchases. This is repeateв for not all users.

That is situation that a user makes a purchase on WP8 within an application and enjoys paid functionality. Updated on WP8.1 - internal purcahse disappears. I note that in the code there is a check in the store on the availability of purchase.

The same behavior if the user to reset the phone to factory settings - internal purchases disappear.

Nobody faced with such a problem?